# Bubble Graph in JQuery

Tags: jquery, charts

Does anyone know of a jquery plugin which can create a bubble graph?

Here's what it needs to look like:

http://www.bellschofield.eu/index.php

I've been using JS Charts but that is only capable of producing Pie/Line/Bar.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Link is busted for me...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://raphaeljs.com/ with http://g.raphaeljs.com/

(Not jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jqChart jQuery Plugin](http://www.jqchart.com/samples/ChartTypes/BubbleChart)